# ionic pro gives an error ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have pushed my project to the ionic pro repository and i have got the error in building the project in ionic pro online

```
Error: Failed to transpile program
at new BuildError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:137:20
at Promise ()
at transpileWorker (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:103:12)
at Object.transpile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:61:12)
at buildProject (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:97:78)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:47:16
at 
npm info lifecycle ionic-hello-world@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@1.0.0 build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab-runner/.npm/_logs/2017-10-10T09_34_40_291Z-debug.log
npm run build failed
Make sure your project has a build script in the package.json
Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I don't have an idea what to do and how to do?

**ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.1

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v7.8.0
npm               : 4.2.0 
OS                : Linux 4.4

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Please help me out and all suggestions are appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you show `ionic info`?

Comment: Sure, i will write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using very old `app-scripts` version.You must update it to latest.

This is very old:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
```

Latest version is [**3.0.0**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/releases)

And also use [**latest Ionic 3.7.1**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.7.1) too.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)